# javascript compute mistake (calculator)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a calculator using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. Everything worked out fine until I came to coding the compute (`=`) button.

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="button" value=" = " onclick="compute()">
```

This is my JS:

```
function compute() {
    var input_var = document.getElementById('input');
    ans = Math.floor(+eval(input_var.value));
    document.getElementById('answer').value = '=' + 'ans';
}
```

If anyone that knows how to solve what's wrong, I would greatly appreciate it if you could reply.

Comment: You need to post more than that for people to help you. We have no context of how your DOM looks like, what you intend etc.

Comment: You haven't indicated the expected and actual (undesired) behavior, you should also probably post more of your HTML. Check out [ask] and [mcve]. It's often important for others to be able to reproduce bugs in your code in order to help solve them.

Comment: Try being more precise with your wording, elaborating on what went wrong. You can also add all the html/css/javascript using 7th icon in editor

Comment: why `Math.floor`? maybe you entered the wonderful world of floating point calculation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should post the **whole code** to get accurate solution!

Probably these could be some of the errors:

1. Set **id attribute** of your **=** button with value **"input"**
2. 3rd line should be: `ans = Math.floor(eval(+input_var.value));`
3. 4th line should be: `document.getElementById('answer').value = '=' + ans;` as [StaticBeagle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6383857/staticbeagle) has also mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should be lucky that you made the mistake to put the variable in quotes. That's why you don't get a value other than the literal string `=ans`(maybe, we don't know as you didn't post all code that's needed to give a better answer).

Back to why you're lucky.

Never use `eval`! eval is evil. (Unless you know what you do, but you don't the next couple of years). To parse a number, you'd use `Number(input_var.value)`.

The next error is that you create a global variable by omitting one of `var, let, const` for your `ans` declaration.

The next thing you shouldn't do is to use inline javascript. We use `eventListener` instead. As said before, it's impossible to answer more specific as your question lacks too many details - however I'll show you how you get a value by pressing a button in the console.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  // prevent submitting the form (I guess another error in your code)
  e.preventDefault();
  const value = Number(document.getElementById('input').value);
  console.log('The value is: ' + value);
}, false);
```

```html
<form id="foo">
  <input type="number" id="input">
  <input type="submit" value=" = ">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if ans is a local or global variable, but if its intention is to be a local variable then you should have it like this:

`var ans = Math.floor(eval(+input_var.value));`

Also, because you're setting the value of your element to `'=' + 'ans'` you're actually setting it to the actual string 'ans'. If you want to refer to what `ans` is you should write it like this:

```
document.getElementById('answer').value = '=' + ans;
```